# PHP-MySQL: add leading zero to TIMESTAMPDIFF Concatenated output

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'd like to display a time difference between two datetime and my current approach works, except that when the hours, minutes and seconds are under 10, it only displays a single digit and i'd like to add the leading zero to the output.

the query looks like this.

```
SELECT *,
CONCAT(
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, start_time, end_time), 24), ':',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time), 60), ':',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, start_time, end_time), 60)
) AS total_time
FROM test_db
```

it outputs the following results when the time digit is less than 10.

```
4:53:21
10:1:9
6:3:8
```

My goal is for the output to display as follows.

```
04:53:21
10:01:09
06:03:08
```

Note: I am passing this results to an array which is then sent to an AJAX callback to output the results on a dynamically generated table. If there is a better solution that could work using jquery/ajax, then I am more than open to any suggestions. However, since I will eventually need to export this results to an excel file, I have been leaning towards a query solution instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to prepend a leading zero, and then take the rightmost two characters...

```
 RIGHT(CONCAT('0', expr ),2)
```

This only works if the values of expr are non-negative, and no more than two digits.

---

As an entirely different approach, you could get the difference in seconds, and convert to TIME datatype...

```
  SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,start_time,end_time),24*60*60))
```

The hour portion could still be less than two digits, so you could apply the same pattern as above... prepending a `'0'` character, and taking the rightmost eight characters.

Or, you could just wrap that in a `DATE_FORMAT( timeexpr, '%T')`

Comment: I'm testing with your suggestions right now to see which one works. I will post back my results shortly.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you for leading me to the right direction. SEC_TO_TIME(MOD(..) worked but it kept returning 2 digits for hours with 3 digits but then I remembered you mentioned that I would keep getting 2 digits max due to the MOD, so I did the simplest thing I could. Took away the MOD part and used SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) and the output was 475:41:34 and also 02:17:41. so mission accomplished captain. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that the `TIME` datatype allows for values in the range `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`. Hour values of 839 or greater will cause an overflow. My example included `MOD` because that's what the original query was doing. (I only answered the question about adding the "missing" leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TIME_FORMAT and SEC_TO_TIME in combination and avoid using MOD() function to not limit the hours to 2 digits output.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, start_time, end_time)),'%H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
  DATE_FORMAT(concat part, '%H:%m:%s')
```

and see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks krasipenkov. I tried positioning the DATE_FORMAT as DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(....), '%H:%m:%s') as you suggested but it returns NULL.